# I am getting error "Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded" when I use mailing in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-9

**I am getting error "Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded" when I use mailing in laravel**

**env**
It's my env file which I copy from mailtrap

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=307f3b9d88a7bd
MAIL_PASSWORD=20b0d000da4785
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS= ranahamzaghy@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

**route/web.php**
Its my route

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;


Route::get('send-mail', function () {
$details = [
'title' => 'Mail from ItSolutionStuff.com',
'body' => 'This is for testing email using smtp'
    ];
 Mail::to('ranahamzaghy@gmail.com')->send(new App\Mail\TestMail($details));
 dd("Email is Sent.");
 });
```

**resources/views/emails/mail.blade.php**
Its my blade

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>rajtechnologies.com</title>
</head>
<body>

<p>Thank you</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**app/Mail/TestMail.php**
Its my mail

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class TestMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject('Mail from rajtechnologies.com')->view('emails.mail');
    }
}
```

Comment: Erm... is that your actual username and password?

Comment: yeah brother ...

Comment: are you sending any image in mail?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, you can change the MAIL_PORT in your .env file.

The allowed ports are:

25, 465, 587 and 2525

So, change MAIL_PORT=587 for example, your mail will be sent.